# Why do I get an overflow / #INF error, when attempting to position chart label?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have the following procedure, which I use to add labels to a chart:

```
Sub add_comments(apply_to As Series, source_range As Range)
  Dim i As Long
  Dim c As Range

  If source_range.Count > apply_to.Points.Count Then
    Set source_range = source_range.Resize(apply_to.Points.Count, 1)
  End If

  i = 1
  For Each c In source_range
    If Not IsError(c) And i <= apply_to.Points.Count Then
      If Len(c.Text) <> 0 Then
        apply_to.Points(i).HasDataLabel = True
        apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Text = c.Value2
        apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle
        With apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Format.Line
          .Visible = msoTrue
          .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
        apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
        Debug.Print apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top
        apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top = apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top - (10 + apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Height)
      Else
        If apply_to.Points(i).HasDataLabel Then
          apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Delete
        End If
      End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next c

  apply_to.HasLeaderLines = True
End Sub
```

However, when I run the sub, it aborts on the line `apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top = apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top - (10 + apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Height)` with an overflow error. Trying to print the value of `apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top` makes it seem like there is a problem with fetching the top value of the datalabel:
[image]

However, looking at the graph, the label seems to have a valid position, and should have a `.Top` value.

[image]

Can someone give me a pointer to what is going wrong in my procedure, please?

Comment: What happens if you replace `10` with `10.0` or `10#` ?

Comment: I agree with CallumDA this is likely to be a type variable issue.   Change code to what CallumDA suggested or place the `10` at the end of the expression.

Comment: I already tested for this before posting here. Besides, if this was an error created by adding the wrong datatype to the .top value, `Debug.Print apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top` should not print `1,#INF` to the immediate window. @SMeaden

Comment: What is the value of apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Top - (10 + apply_to.Points(i).DataLabel.Height)